# SSIS Download all files from SharePoint 365 Library

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis, sharepoint-online

Good morning, I have a library in SharePoint Online 365 where I have stored excel and csv files with .xlsx/.csv extension, I have the requirement to download all the files that are stored in the library with an SSIS package to automate this task, I have currently made an SSIS package following this tutorial: https://sql-listo.com/ssis/descargar-archivos-sharepoint-via-ssis/ where I know the filename but only I can download a single file from the library at each execution of the SSIS package, I have tried to modify the code so that it downloads all the stored files but I have not been successful, This is the code with which I download a single file. Please help me to make it possible to download all the files stored in the SharePoint library.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ST_2f30fe55bd774ea1846364938bdb2a74
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        private SecureString _password;
        private string password;
        private string UserName;
        private string SiteUrl;
        private string FileUrl;
        private string FolderDestination;
        public void Main()
        {
            SiteUrl = Dts.Variables["User::SiteUrl"].Value.ToString();
            FileUrl = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
            UserName = Dts.Variables["User::UserName"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();
            password = Dts.Variables["User::Password"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();
            FolderDestination = Dts.Variables["User::FolderDestination"].Value.ToString();

            Stream filestrem = GetFile();
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUrl);
            string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderDestination, fileName);

            FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath, (int)filestrem.Length);
            // Initialize the bytes array with the stream length and then fill it with data
            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[filestrem.Length];
            filestrem.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
            // Use write method to write to the file specified above
            fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);

        }
        SecureString Password
        {
            get
            {

                if (_password == null)
                {
                    _password = GetPasswordFromConsoleInput(password);
                }

                return _password;
            }
        }
        private static SecureString GetPasswordFromConsoleInput(string password)
        {
            //Get the user's password as a SecureString
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            char[] arrPassword = password.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char c in arrPassword)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            return securePassword;
        }

        public Stream GetFile()
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = GetContextObject())
            {

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web, website => website.ServerRelativeUrl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Regex regex = new Regex(SiteUrl, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string strSiteRelavtiveURL = regex.Replace(FileUrl, string.Empty);
                string strServerRelativeURL = CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl, strSiteRelavtiveURL);

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(strServerRelativeURL);
                clientContext.Load(oFile);
                ClientResult<Stream> stream = oFile.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                return this.ReadFully(stream.Value);
            }
        }

        private ClientContext GetContextObject()
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, Password);
            return context;
        }

        public string CombineUrl(string path1, string path2)
        {

            return path1.TrimEnd('/') + '/' + path2.TrimStart('/');
        }
        private Stream ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()); ;
            }
        }

    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
}
```

Mention that I have investigated and found some examples on the web but I have not been able to make them work so I chose to adapt the previous code for this requirement.